# code to prevent DOS attack in python

Tags: python

I have a multi-client server code in which multiple clients are connected to a server.
Now all the clients are sending text messages to the server and are receiving a reply from the server. Now if one client tries to flood the server using a syn flood which the client runs in a different terminal then I want the server to close the connection of the client and the server still continues messaging with the other clients.
In short its how to prevent a DOS attack?

Comment: Is there a reason why you believe that this should be handled by Python and not the server itself?  For example, you can use `iptables` in linux to limit syn traffic.

Comment: guys I need a shell script which I can run in a terminal and which stops flooding or blocks the IP of that client, or even closes the connection from that IP.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with a syn flood, you don't do that in Python. A syn flood is one machine sending a large amount of syn packages to your server, leading to an exhaustion of *kernel resources*.

The attack takes advantage of the fact that connection attempts are fully handled by the kernel. As such, your application will only get notified of a new connection after it was fully created (which will not happen in a syn-flood). Instead, your socket's backlog will quickly fill up and there will be no more connections attempts possible until the half-open connections time out.

As such, you'll have to handle this in the kernel, e.g. by increasing the socket's backlog (note that even half-open connections require some memory unless you use syn-cookies or similar) or by limiting the amount of syn-packets which are allowed to be received e.g. with iptables or other firewalls.

Generally, if the socket's backlog is full, no new connections will be accepted. Existing connections will not be affected by this and will continue to be served. Generally, when receiving a syn-flood, there are other kernel resources seriously strained which means, you might still have problems communicating depending on the actual circumstances.

To say it clear again: handling syn-floods is not a thing you'll be able to handle in Python but have to deal with by properly configuring your kernel.